# .htaccess: Wordpress permalink code interferes with redirect to mobile version of the website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I have a WordPress site with a permalink structure, which means there is a rewrite code added by WordPress to the .htaccess file.

The problem is that when I add a redirect to the mobile version of the site for mobile users, there is some sort of interference with the WordPress permalink code in the .htacess file.

For example, when I do the Google Mobile Friendly Test, it says that it cannot access the site (neither the desktop version nor the mobile version).

When I remove the WordPress code in the .htaccess and leave only the mobile redirect code in there, then the Mobile Friendly Test works just fine, but of course all the permalinks stop working on the desktop site and give a 404.

How can I stop the mobile redirect from interfering with the WordPress code in the .htaccess?

Here is the complete .htaccess I am using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /

    # prevent looping
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.website\.com

    # Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
    RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

    # Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
    RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

    # cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
    RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

    # Check if this looks like a mobile device
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^$

    # Check if we're not already on the mobile site
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.
    # Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !\mobile=0(;|$)
    # Now redirect to the mobile site
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems like it was the cache plugin in WordPress that was creating the problems with the mobile redirects.